# Jhipster Angular 2 Lazy Loading Module Not found Exception

Tags: angular, angular-cli, jhipster

I created the Jhipster application and try to add the lazy loading module, which give the module not found exception.

### I follow the "https://jaseb.github.io/angular2-example/" article but still the same exception. I try myself. Please help me us to proceed further.Please find the code snippets as follows.

## app.route.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {NavbarComponent} from "./layouts/navbar/navbar.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: NavbarComponent, outlet: 'navbar'},
    { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'app/modules/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hi Roman, When i try to invoke the lazy url pattern it has to lazily as per my code. But am getting "app/modules/lazy/lazy.module" not found exception. When i try to run the application standalone as a angular-cli project its working, but as jhipster project it gives the module not found error. Pls help to identify the case.

Comment: I have the same problem with this repo: https://github.com/dancancro/jhipster-sample-app-ng2/blob/newmodules/src/main/webapp/app/module/module.routing.ts#L15 Did you solve it?

Comment: I have same problem for load module on routing using lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

First you must install webpack plugin angular-router-loader

```
npm install angular-router-loader --save-dev
```

then in your project directory open webpack/webpack.common.js and add angular-router-loader after awesome-typescript-loader like below

```
loaders: [
'angular2-template-loader',
'awesome-typescript-loader',
'angular-router-loader' // here
]
```

path should be without app prefix

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './modules/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
```

Comment: that's not working, jHipster support lazyloading or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with lazy loading working in a straight angular app.
I compared a working app with mine and noticed that  I did not have "baseUrl": "./" in my tsconfig.spec.json nor my tsconfig.app.json.
Once I added it it started working.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",  **<-- this was missing**
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps