# Jhipster Angular lazy - loading support available or not?

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-routing

I already read that question on stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170723/jhipster-angular-2-lazy-loading-module-not-found-exception), but I ask again for more description for my problem.

I try to load admin module after login successfully and that admin module load using lazy-loading. my project structure below.

[image]

I try to load AdminModule using lazy loading.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from  '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path:'', component:LoginComponent },
            { path:'admin',loadChildren:'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'}
        ])
    ],
    exports:[
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRouterModule{
    constructor(){
        console.log("App Router Module call");
    }
}
```

**admin-routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from "./admin.component";
import { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard/dashboard.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: AdminComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: DashboardComponent,
                        pathMatch: 'full'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {

}
```

If i go default routing it's work fine, but when i go at admin i got 
  error.
  **Cannot find module. and  webpackEmptyContext**

[image]

If do that using angular-cli using official way then that's working 
  fine for me but using Jhipster generator that has error, for some 
  reason must be used Jhipster.

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const ENV = 'dev';
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const fs = require('fs');
const ddlPath = './build/www/vendor.json';

if (!fs.existsSync(ddlPath)) {
    execSync('webpack --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js');
}

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './build/www',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console'
            ],
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
            secure: false
        }]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build/www'),
        filename: 'app/[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                'tslint-loader'
            ],
            exclude: ['node_modules', new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9000,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:9060'
            }
        }, {
            reload: false
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new writeFilePlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
            path.resolve('./src/test'),
        ])
    ]
});
```

Comment: Can you add webpack.config.json?

Comment: i cant find webpack.config.json file that hase webpack folder that has webpack.common.js , webpack.dev.js, webpacj.prod.js, and webpack.vender.js

Comment: webpack.dev.js is your webpack config for dev

Comment: i can add that file on question.

Comment: Did you add `angular-router-loader` to `webpack.common.js`?

Comment: yes i add that in loaders array.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, was able to fix it by changing values in **tsconfig-aot**

had to set `complierOptions.module` to `"commonjs"`